# Query for fuel usage with a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

Searched Stackoverflow, and was not able to find an answer to my question (maybe it's there, but did not see one).

Have the following query which lists the mileage used, fuel cost, and fuel quantity for multiple vehicles stored at a location in the MAIN table. Also have a sub-query to calculate the cost per mile - and in that subquery is a WHERE clause to not calculate unless the fuel_qty > 0 (cannot divide by zero, unless you are Chuck Norris - ha ha). Also need to display a zero for the fuel_qty (in line 3 of this query) if it is a zero value. Am getting an error with this query - saying that it is "not a single-group group function". Is there something which I am missing or not seeing?

Have tried adding cost_per_mile to the group by clause, but received an "invalid identifier" error. Then also added a group by clause to the subquery - but that also did not work.

```
select cost.mileage_useage
     , cost.fuel_cost
     , cost.fuel_qty
     , (select (sum(cost1.mileage_usage / cost1.fuel_qty) * cost1.fuel_cost)
        from cost cost1
        where cost1.fuel_qty > 0) as cost_per_mile
from cost
inner join main on main.equip_no = cost.equip_no
where main.stored_loc = 4411
group by 
     cost.mileage_useage
   , cost.fuel_cost
   , cost.fuel_qty
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do would all be really helpful.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sample data I believe would be something like this...
mileage_usage = 410
fuel_cost = 3.20
fuel_qty = 25
cost_per_mile = 32.48

Comment: Are `cost` and `cost1` separate tables?

Comment: @BobJarvis - no cost1 is the subquery to differentiate between the COST table and the same table used in the subquery. Probably did not write that exactly correctly. Have changed the given script example to make that more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Why doesn't this do what you want?

```
select c.mileage_useage, c.fuel_cost, c.fuel_qty,
       (sum(c.mileage_usage) * c.fuel_cost /
        nullif(c.fuel_qty, 0)
       ) as cost_per_mile
from cost c inner join
     main m
     on m.equip_no = c.equip_no
where main.stored_loc = 4411
group by c.mileage_useage, c.fuel_cost, c.fuel_qty
```

Comment: There are some instances where the mileage_usage is a negative number. Perhaps that has something to do with this? Thank you for your answer, but it does not seem to work

Comment: Hummm... once I added a nullif to the mileage_usage, it kinda worked. Think I may need to look at this further. Thank you @GordonLinoff !!

Comment: @Rebecca . . . I don't know what a negative number would mean.  Perhaps you should ask another question, dealing with negative numbers in that column.

Answer (score 0):

Believe I found an answer - thank you for all your help! This takes into consideration if the mileage useage = 0 or is a negative number. Also if the fuel quantity = 0 then that portion of the equation is not possible to divide by a zero value. It may look a little strange, but this works!

```
select cost.mileage_useage
     , cost.fuel_cost
     , cost.fuel_qty
     , ( sum(((CASE WHEN cost.mileage_usage = 0 THEN 1
         WHEN cost.mileage_usage < 0 THEN TO_NUMBER(NULL)
         ELSE cost.mileage_usage END) 
         / DECODE(eq_cost.fuel_qty,0, 1, eq_cost.fuel_qty)) 
         * eq_cost.fuel_cost )) as cost_per_mile
from cost
inner join main on main.equip_no = cost.equip_no
where main.stored_loc = 4411
group by cost.mileage_useage
      , cost.fuel_cost
      , cost.fuel_qty
```

Answer (score 0):

You can further simplify it as following:

```
select cost.mileage_useage
     , cost.fuel_cost
     , cost.fuel_qty
     , sum((CASE WHEN cost.mileage_usage = 0 THEN eq_cost.fuel_cost
         WHEN cost.mileage_usage > 0 THEN cost.mileage_usage * eq_cost.fuel_cost END) 
         / (case when eq_cost.fuel_qty = 0 then 1 else eq_cost.fuel_qty end)) as cost_per_mile
from cost
inner join main on main.equip_no = cost.equip_no
where main.stored_loc = 4411
group by cost.mileage_useage
      , cost.fuel_cost
      , cost.fuel_qty;
```

Cheers!!